# Передача значения в шаблон из class.php

Tags: php, битрикс

У меня в файле `class.php` есть функция создания нового элемента инфоблока:

```
function createRequest() {
   ob_end_clean();
   global $USER;
   $rsUser = CUser::GetByID($USER->GetID());
   $user = $rsUser->Fetch();
   $el = new CIBlockElement;
   $PRODUCT_ID = $el->Add(array(
      'IBLOCK_ID' => intval($this->arParams["REQUEST_IBLOCK_ID"]),
      'NAME' => "Заявка ".date("d.m.Y H:i:s"),
      'ACTIVE' => 'Y',
      'ACTIVE_FROM' => date("d.m.Y H:i:s"),
      "PREVIEW_TEXT" => json_encode($_REQUEST["obj"]),
      'PROPERTY_VALUES' => array(
      'DEPARTMENT_ID' => $user["UF_DEPARTMENT"][0])
      )
    ); 
    $this->includeComponentTemplate("excel");
    die();
}
```

Каким образом мне передать id созданного элемента `$PRODUCT_ID` в шаблон `$this->includeComponentTemplate("excel")`, чтобы там с ней как-то работать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В шаблон компонента передается поле arResult (массив) (в шаблоне это будет уже переменная)

В классе:

```
$this->arResult["PRODUCT_ID"] = $PRODUCT_ID; 
$this->includeComponentTemplate("excel");
```

В шаблоне

```
Создана заявка с номером №<?=$arResult["PRODUCT_ID"]?>
```

[Документация по компонентам](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&CHAPTER_ID=04565&LESSON_PATH=3913.4565)